# Getting RGBA values from .png in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

For a project I need to get the RGBA values from an image and use them in later calculations. To do this, I have been using im.getdata() and because this gives me the values in the format of lists within a list I wrote some code to put it into one long list instead.

```
for group in pix_val:
    for item in group:
        pix_val_flat.append(item)
```

This worked perfectly well for me until I tested the code with an entirely white image. Instead of producing sets of 4 values within a list, it just gave me one long list - which means I get an error when my program tries to flatten the list. Anyone understand why this happens and how I could fix it?

This is my code:

```
im=Image.open("/filelocation")
pix_val=list(im.getdata())
pix_val_flat=[]
for group in pix_val:
    for item in group:
        pix_val_flat.append(item)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/program", line 286 in <module>
        for item in group:
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The problem is in group. Its returning int in this case. Means pix_val is array of integer instead of being array of array of integers.

Try to check output of each method by printf..

Understand the difference from there.

Comment: I suspect your pure white image has been converted to a palette image which has just one value for each pixel (which is the index into the palette) rather than 4 RGBA values for each pixel. If you want an RGBA image, use `x=Image.open('name.png').convert('RGBA')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks so much, that explains a lot. Will give it a go!

Answer (score 2):

Edited this line of my code and it now works:

```
im=Image.open("/filelocation").convert('RGBA')
```

Comment: Well done! You can accept your own answer and bag the points.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `list(im.getdata())` or `numpy.array(im.getdata())` (You're probably better off with the first one.)  It's somehow returning a single long list instead of a list of lists and this might mitigate that.  Another option is to use something like `imageio.imread(filename)`, which returns the pixel values as a numpy array, rather than a sequence.  Then you can reference array dimensions like you can in any other array.  (e.g. `image[:, :, 0]` would give you all your R values.)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use `img.load()` it makes working with single pixels way easier.

```
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open("n.png")
pixels = img.load()

pix_val_flat = [v for c in [[x,y] for x in range(img.size[0]) for y in range(img.size[1])] for v in pixels[c[0],c[1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get an error is that your `group` variable turns into an `ìnt` value at some point. The `im.getdata()` function is responsible for that, it stacks the RGB values to one single value. You can write a simple workaround to check, whether group is an int value or a tuple (as you expect). Something like that should work:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("test.png")
pix_val = list(im.getdata())
pix_val_flat = []

for group in pix_val:
    if type(group) == int:
        group (group, group, group, 0) # if int, change it to tupel
    for item in group:
        pix_val_flat.append(item)
```